# sequential steps functions?

Tags: javascript, function

I want to do something that can be passed through a function immediately after a value

for example:

```
// my value
let str = "example";

// my func
let sum = value => {
  if(value.length + 1 == 7) { return true; }
  else{ return false; }
}

// I want it to work when I write it like this.
console.log(  "awesome".sum()  )
```

Comment: remove the console log, remove the "awesome" string and just call it as sum()

Comment: You will have to write it on `String.prototype`. That might still not work for `"awesome".sum()`. You will either have to do `("awesome").sum()` or `var str = "awesome"; str.sum()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // I want it to work when I write it like this.

You need to add the method to `String.prototype`

```
String.prototype.sum = function()
{
   return this.length + 1 == 7;
};
```

Or simply

```
String.prototype.sum = function()
{
   return this.length === 6;
};
```

Comment: As an extension to answer, you should use `===` and ` + 1 === 7` is unnecessary, in my POV. You can do `.length === 6`

Comment: very beautiful as I want.  Does it apply only to text here? Do I have to write a different formula for an array or object? What is the name of this  when I can go on to investigate in more detail.

Comment: For Array, Number and Objects, you need to add this method to their prototype. This will work only with strings.

Comment: @Rajesh I know it's unnecessary I just made an example to show you better what I want to tell :)

Comment: How can I investigate in more detail? This works well, but I want to learn more.

Comment: gurvinder372 No offense taken, even if you meant. @VolkanÇiloğlu Just a minor pointer. Keeping a generic function name as `sum` can go against you. Always prefer having very specific names and try to avoid mutating prototypes. Better to create a utility and use it. That makes it reusable and safe.

Answer (score 1):

Add the function in `String.prototype`

```js
String.prototype.sum = function(){
  if(this.length + 1 == 7) { return true; }
  else{ return false; }
}

console.log(  "awesome".sum()  )
console.log(  "awesom".sum()  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the **String** class.

**Standard**

```
let str = "example";

String.prototype.sum = value => {
  if(value.length + 1 == 7) { return true; }
  else{ return false; }
}

console.log(  "awesome".sum(3)  )
```

**ES6**

```
Object.assign(String.prototype, {
  sum (value) {
     if(value.length + 1 == 7) { return true; }
     else{ return false; }
  }
});
```

Comment: check other's answer. and this is not OP asked.

Comment: Can you add a full example of using `assign` in this case?

Comment: Your standard function will not work. I'll leave it to you to understand why.